# XNA game components

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, xnanimation

I an confused about how to pass values of variables from 1 gamecomponent to another.
I am using xna 4.0.

I created two gamecomponents, the drawstring and the inputmanager. 
I want to read the keyboard input of the user and pass it onto drawstring where it will update the position.

I cant add components on drawstring(drawablegamecomponent).
I can do it on class but not on gamecomponent.
Can you guys post some examples here. For beginners.

Comment: I think the correct answer to this question is "Don't use `GameComponent`". You can write your own classes. You can write your own interfaces. For this you can probably just use a method. Then you can, you know, *just pass your variables* (as, say, arguments to a method). `GameComponent` [kinda sucks](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9209/288) anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GameComponent` for something that you would want to have `Update` called on every frame, and use `DrawableGameComponent` for something that you would want to have `Draw` called on every frame and `LoadContent` called when appropriate (at the start of the program, as well as whenever the device is lost, like when the user pressed ***Ctrl-Alt-Del*** on Windows).

For `InputManager` you might want an `Update` method, so that you can keep user input updated, so `InputManager` could be a `GameComponent`. `DrawString` doesn't sound like it needs to be. Both classes sound like they could be services. In the constructor or `Initialize` method of your game class, do something like the following:

```
Components.Add(mInputManager = new InputManager(this));
Services.AddService(typeof(InputManager), mInputManager);
Services.AddService(typeof(DrawString), mDrawString = new DrawString(this))
```

(`DrawString` and any other class that you want to get game services from will need a reference to the `Game` object.)

(Note that `GameComponent`s do not necessarily need to be services, and services do not need necessarily need to be `GameComponent`s. To get `Update` and/or `Draw` to be called, you must call `Components.Add(...)`; separately, to get an object to be retrievable as a service, you must call `Services.AddService(...)`).

Then, when you would like to use the `InputManager` or `DrawString` service in some other game component (or any class that you have passed a reference to your game object), you can do this:

```
InputManager input = (InputManager)Game.Services.GetService(typeof(InputManager));
```

Personally, I write an extension method to make that more concise:

```
using XNAGame = Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Game;

...

   public static T GetService<T>(this XNAGame pXNAGame)
   {
      return (T)pXNAGame.Services.GetService(typeof(T));
   }
```

The line to get the input service then becomes:

```
InputManager input = Game.GetService<InputManager>();
```