# Is it possible to run a XNA game after exiting another?

Tags: c#, xna

Is it possible to run a XNA game after exiting another?
I tried to write at the default XNA's "Program.cs":

```
using (Game1 game = new Game1())
{
    game.Run();
}

using (Game2 game = new Game2())
{
    game.Run();
}
```

but after exiting the first game the second was running once and then just exited the game....

edit:
I found that when I try to exit the window with the X button (of the window...) the second game window starts...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `OnExiting()` method in your `Game1` class to create a new instance of a game when one is closed.

```
protected override void OnExiting(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    using (Game2 game = new Game2())
    {
        game.Run();
    }
    base.OnExiting(sender, args);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but after debugging I found that it's still doing only one run and then exiting the second game

Comment: OHHH... What are you using to exit the game? (You are using code right, NOT the X button?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, you can accomplish what you are trying to do, by using [Game Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent.aspx) instead.

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do here, but more than likely there is a better solution.

More information on game components [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372818/xna-game-components).